# How smart contracts written in solidity be expressed in legal prose so it becomes legally enforcing/binding?

Tags: solidity

How can smart contracts written in solidity be expressed in legal prose so it becomes legally enforcing/binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find someone who is an expert in both Solidity and legal prose. He will be able to translate Solidity contracts to legal contracts.

I can see how it can be useful in some cases to shield from bugs in Solidity code.

Comment: Understood - Thanks! How will the legal authorities enforce it though? Is there some sort of a legal-solidity parsing tool?

Comment: I think it can be enforced via court same as any other legal contract. Solidity-to-legal translator app sounds like an interesting idea. It seems like a very hard task though that would probably require machine learning to solve.

Comment: I think everyone who's into smart contracts should start reading laws and maybe engaging in a "smart-law" (heh) firms that specialize in this kind of translations. if smart contracts start getting mainstream, this kind of firms will become vital.